# make ajax uploader as htmlhelper

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I use mvc4 and i have an action that can handle upload file our image in jquery ajax. i use this action on page with this code

```
@Html.Action("imagesender", "admin", new { @name = "image" })
```

so some javascript,css and html code will added to my page and after uploading return file name in hidden filed so i can save it into my database.

i want to make custom html helper that make it work easier but i can't include javascript and css code.
Please give some solution
thanks

Comment: We would really like to help you, but the way you are _asking_ is plain wrong. You should show at least a **minimal** effort of your research being done to reach your goal. Please refer the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for further information. Also you could refer these [set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload?rq=1) of SO answers to guide you closer.